# One string contains another string

Tags: java, string, compare

Need Help on String concepts in java,

```
 String s1="Java is oop probgramming, R1|R2|R4|R5|R";
 String s2="R";
 String s3="R2";
 String s4="R5";
```

I want to compare to s2, s3, s4 with s1 string compare after `,`
I have tried fallowing

```
System.out.println(s3.matches(s1.substring(Options1.indexOf(","), s1.indexOf("|"))));
System.out.println(s2.matches(s1.substring(Options1.indexOf(","), s1.indexOf("|"))));
```

I am getting the false both statements.

I want when I compare to `s2` string with `s1` it should `true`.

Comment: Split it according to "," then use `contains` on the second part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you want something like this:

```
String s1="Java is oop programming, R1|R2|R4|R5|R";
String s2="R";
String s3="R2";
String s4="R5";
String[] validTargets = new String[]{s2,s3,s4};

String alternatives = s1.split(",")[1].trim();
for(String s: alternatives.split("|")){
    for(String t: validTargets){
        if(s.matches(t)) { //you can also use equals() here..
            System.out.println("they are matched!");
        }
    }
}
```

it will compare the substrings separated by `|` after `,`  - with your targets (s2,s3,s4 in this case) and check whether they are exactly the same string or not..

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be done simply with `String#contains` -

```
s1.contains(s2);
s1.contains(s3);
```

Comment: Not sure, but if the string were `"Java is oop probgramming, R1|R2|R4|R5` I don't think he'd like to get `true` when checking with `R`. I may be wrong though.

Comment: I think OP want to check whether particular string exist in a specific position

Comment: :D that is very funny matter and there is no difference in both way, one is simple and easier and other is not

Answer (score 0):

You may use regular expressionas shown below :

```
System.out.println(s1.matches("(?i).*"+s2+"*"));
System.out.println(s1.matches("(?i).*"+s3+"*"));
System.out.println(s1.matches("(?i).*"+s4+"*"));
```

If you want to compare it after `,` than get substring of string `s1` and than use above code.

```
 s1 = s1.substring(s1.indexOf(","));
```

May this help you.